# Can't figure out how to get fzf to ignore ~/Library ~/Applications and ~/Music on OSX

Tags: terminal, zsh

I've gotten fzf to work on MacOS X Ventura with the Kitty terminal, and it's great!

Alt+T and Alt+C work as expected, but there's one fly in the ointment.

I can't get either of them to ignore all the spurious files in ~/Library ~/Applications or ~/Music

My environment variables look like this:

```
export FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND="fd . $HOME"
export FZF_CTRL_T_COMMAND="$FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND"
export FZF_ALT_C_COMMAND="fd -t d . $HOME"
```

The [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) docs say it should ignore anything in my ~/.config/git/ignore, and I've tried adding:

```
Library
Applications
Music
```

```
**/Library
**/Applications
**/Music
```

As well as a bunch of other combinations with no success.

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: Can you point out the part in the manual where it describes file/directory exclusion via the file you mentioned? I didn’t see any details on this on the linked page.

Comment: If you're putting stuff in `~/.config/git/ignore`, I would expect that to represent absolute path names, not relative ones, right?  `fd` supports `gitignore`, but it's not meant as a general exclusions mechanism, it's meant for `fd` to know what to ignore when you're in a repository.

Comment: @feoh Leaving my previous comment there for the moment, but are we talking about `fd` or `fzf`?  Or are you piping `fd` INTO `fzf` ?

Comment: @MarcWilson Not sure what you're asking.

The fzf utility uses another utility like fd or rg or whatever to actually do the file searching. So in the end analysis we need that utility to ignore the OSX special files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end analysis, the answer turned out to be adding the absolute paths to $HOME/.config/fd/ignore.

I think Marc Wilson was on the right track, but in the end analysis I decided that putting the restrictions into fd's config was the better choice.

Thanks for the commnts!